# Groovy Regex for matching words (even with accented letters)

Tags: regex, groovy, diacritics

I'm trying to tokenize words from any text, e.g.:

```
Ça me plaît.
```

Should be tokenized as "ça,me,plaît".
To do this, I want to clear the string from all special characters, and then split it on a whitespace. With this code:

```
text = text.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/^\w/, ' ')
def tokens = text.split(" ")
```

I get

```
a me pla t
```

Which is far from being useful.
What regex do I need here?

Thanks!
Mulone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me (at least for this situation):

```
'Ça me plaît.'.toLowerCase().replaceAll( /[^\p{javaLowerCase}]/, ' ').split( ' ' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use \S (capital S) instead of \w. \S matches all non-white characters, while \s  (non-capital) matches all white characters.

Hence, you'll have

```
text = text.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/^\S/, ' ')
def tokens = text.split(" ")
```

Comment: Actually with \S the regex doesn't filter the dot (and any other special charater). Is there a regex to express any letter in any european alphabet?